# Why can't I find the interface that can reach a specific host?

Tags: java, network-programming, icmp

I want to find the network interface that can be used to join a specific remote host, to I wrote this code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    InetAddress t = InetAddress.getByName("10.10.11.101");

    // generic "icmp/ping" test
    System.out.println(t.isReachable(5000));

    // same thing but for each interface
    final Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nets = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    for(final NetworkInterface netint : Collections.list(nets))
    {
        if(netint.isUp() && !netint.isLoopback())
        {
            System.out.println(t.isReachable(netint, 0, 5000) + " - " + netint);
        }
    }
}
```

The result is :

```
true
false - name:eth4 (Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection)
false - name:eth5 (VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter)
false - name:net6 (Carte Microsoft 6to4)
```

As you can see, generic isReachable tells me that I can reach the specified host, but for unknown reason, when trying to do so on each interface one by one doesn't return a single match. That is odd (in this case this should be the eth4 one that must return true).

Is it a bug ? How can I perform this task (even by using a library) ?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe there is a "trick" on the server-side so it doesn't let you ping so often. This is the only thing that comes to my mind. Try using ping from cmd because I have read that this protocol I not well implemented by Java.

Comment: This don't seems to be the case, as if I disable the first isReachable test the loop one still fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I tried another way to find the interface, here is how I have done it :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    final InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("10.10.11.8");
    final Socket s = new Socket(addr, 80);

    System.out.println(searchInterface(s.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress()));
}

public static NetworkInterface searchInterface(final String interf)
{
    try
    {
        final Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nets = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        for(final NetworkInterface netint : Collections.list(nets))
        {
            if(netint.isUp())
            {
                final Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddresses = netint.getInetAddresses();
                for(final InetAddress inetAddress : Collections.list(inetAddresses))
                {
                    if(inetAddress.getHostAddress().equals(interf))
                    {
                        return netint;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(final SocketException e)
    {
    }

    return null;
}
```

It is not the best way to do it, as you have to know a valid open port on the remote host, but for my problem this is still valid.